# Finding position and orientation of a Frame on another frame in 3D Space

Tags: 3d, transformation

I am trying to figure out how to fine the position and orientation of a frame (Frame_B) in another frame (Frame_A)

I have this data:

- 3 points (P1_A, P2_A, P3_A) in Frame_A, these points define Frame_B plane xy.
- The vector P1_A, P2_A is parallel to X axis of Frame_B.
- The vector P1_A, P3_A is parallel to Y axis of Frame_B. ***
- 3 points (P4_A, P5_A, P6_A) in Frame_A, these points define Frame_B plane xz.
- 3 points (P7_A, P8_A, P9_A) in Frame_A, these points define Frame_B plane yz.

As you can see, I am not a mathematician, so please be gentle.

Thank you very much

Edit: *** I made a mistake in my data:

The vector P1_A, P3_A is parallel to Y axis of Frame_B. not to Z axis of Frame_B.

Here are same detailed data, please see images below
[Image with different points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5KiO3.png)

[Expected position and orientation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06g9J.png)

Edit2:
I managed to find the Frame_B origin coordinates by resolving the 3 planes equations system.
But I have no  idea in how to find the orientations.
Could anyone please help?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have any checks for errors? Like is it possible that your three planes are not perpendicular?

Comment: Hello Andrei, No I have no checks for now, because I know that my planes are perpendicular. but yes, in the next step I will have to check that. Thank you